# How can I turn a converging series/recursive function into a function f(x)

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

I have a series that follows this rule

$n_0 = 30$ This is an arbitrary number that is the start of the series

$n_f = 50$ This number is equally arbitrary. It's the number that the series converges to over time

$r = 0.3$ This is an arbitrary float that is between 0 and 1 inclusive, that describes the rate at which the $n_x$ converges to $n_f.$ When $r = 0,$ it never converges, and when $r = 1,$ it converges instantly, which is fairly clear from the formula used to move through the series:

$$n_x = n_{x-1} + r(n_f - n_{x-1})$$ where $x$ is any positive integer.

I want to know how I can turn this formula for traversing the series into a function $f(x)$ where any positive r rational number be input for x, and it output where the series would be at that point. I first tried to see if it was a quadratic function. Then I realized that it was growing slower than before, and tried to see if it is a logarithm, then I tried to see if it was an exponential function with a fractional exponent, and that didn't work either. I don't know what sort of function it's supposed to be, and I haven't taken calculus yet.

Comment: Let $m_x=n_f-n_x.$ There is a much easier recursion for this.

Comment: I seriously cannot begin to comprehend what that means @Thomas Andrews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a new sequence

$$m_i = n_f - n_i$$

We will compute $m$ instead.

We see that $m_0 = n_f - n_0$. Since $n_f$ and $n_0$ are given, this is enough to specify $m_0$.

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
m_{i + 1} &= n_f - n_{i + 1} \\
&= n_f - (n_i + r(n_f - n_i)) \\
&= (n_f - n_i) - r(n_f - n_i) \\
&= (1 - r)(n_f - n_i) \\
&= (1 - r) m_i
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

Thus, we see that $m$ is a geometric sequence with common ratio $1 - r$. This gives us $m_i = m_0 (1 - r)^i = (n_f - n_0)(1 - r)^i$.

Now we see that $n_i = n_f - m_i$, and therefore we have

$$n_i = n_f - (n_f - n_0)(1 - r)^i$$

Comment: i've never seen a geometric sequence before but this solved the issue exactly. thank you